# can I install GIS on mackbok?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I am trying to install arcgis 10 on apple macbok. But I could not. My question is that whether arcgis 10 is supported by macbook or not?

Comment: How did you try to install? Do you have windows through Parallels? Or bootcamp or something else? These details are necessary.

Comment: Have you tried google it (=RTFM)? I found [this](http://edcommunity.esri.com/software-and-data/mac-os-support) among the first few links.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's supported:

> Many people have asked members of the ESRI Education Team about
>   whether ArcGIS works on Intel-based Macintosh computers. Thanks to
>   some tools presented by Apple and by Parallels, we can respond with a
>   clear “Yes!”, but with the understanding that the user must have a
>   licensed copy of Microsoft Windows XP and be facile with Windows-based
>   operations.

See more at:

- http://blogs.esri.com/esri/gisedcom/2007/09/05/arcgis-on-a-mac/